# python io.open() integer required error

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error when attempting to open a new file with today's date.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\BenPi\stacking\pi3\red_RTS\iotest.py", line 6, in <module>
f = io.open('%s',today, 'w')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here is my code

```
import datetime
import io
import os
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y')
print (today)
f = io.open('%s',today, 'w')
f.write('first line \n')
f.write('second line \n')
f.close()
```

It is my understanding that this is an issue that arises when someone inadvertently uses `os.open()` instead of `io.open()`, which is why I specified the io option. It should be noted that the same error comes up regardless if I import the os module.

I'm using python 3.2.5

Thoughts?

Comment: You already have a string so why are you trying to format at all? `f = io.open(today, 'w')` would do the exact same thing as  `f = io.open("%s" % today, 'w')`

Comment: Agh! Of course, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not formatting correctly, you're using `,` instead of `%`:

```
f = io.open('%s'%today, 'w')
```

Besides, you can just do:

```
f = io.open(today, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

The line
    f = io.open('%s',today, 'w')
should have '%s' first argument the first argument must be the file name.
If you write it like:

```
f = io.open(today, 'w')
```

Just works. Also consider using the "with" statment so in case of an exception the stream will be close anyway such as:

```
with io.open(today, 'w') as f:
    f.write("hello world")
```

I hope I have been helpful.